# jquery onclick not happening - Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-models, django-forms

js:

```
$(".collectionlist").click(function() {
        alert('alert')       
        $.ajax({ 
            data:{
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf_token,
                collection:('{{collection}}')                               
            },
            type:'POST',
            url: '/collect/', 
            cache:false,            
            success: function(response) { 
            return true;                        
            }
        });
      });
```

html:

```
<form action="." method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
<div id="report-collect">
    <button type="submit" class="collectionlist" >Save-Spreadsheet <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/button-icon-ir-fwd.png" width="12" height="17" alt="" /></button>
</form>
</div>
```

For button,i had given a class name,written a jquery function to call the file via ajax.The problem is jquery function is not called,i changed the class name and tried.Tried with alert message,alert is not comming.Onclick is not happening.Need help.

Comment: Is the `collectionlist` submit button dynamically generated?

Comment: Are you putting the script in `document ready` or at the end of your page? (or none of those?)

Comment: @palaѕн,it is a static button

Comment: @Spokey not inside the document ready

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be because of either one of the following reasons

The `collectionlist` element is created dynamically, then you need to use event delegation

```
$(document).on('click', '.collectionlist', function(){
    ....
})
```

Or your script is not running on dom ready

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(".collectionlist").click(function() {
        ....
    });
})
```